# Send a data through Ajax, and the background never receives it

Tags: java, ajax

The foreground sends an ID to the background through Ajax, but the background never receives it. I have been troubled by this problem for a whole day, and I really need your help.Here are my JS and Controller and error messages

```js
$('.category-wrap').on('click', '.now .delete', function (e) {
        var target = e.currentTarget;
        var pc = target.dataset.id;
        var pcId = {'pcId':pc};
        $.confirm('sure？',function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: deleteUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                data:  pcId,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        $.toast('successfully delete！');
                        getList();
                    } else {
                        $.toast('Delete failed！');
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    });
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/removeproductcategory", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> removeProductCategory(@RequestBody Integer pcId,
                                                  HttpServletRequest request) 
{...}
```

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tokgI.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TAmC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you send a json request `var pcId = {'pcId':pc};` and try to receive an Integer `@RequestBody Integer pcId`

try to define a Pojo like this

```
class RequestData {
    public Integer pcId;
}
```

and modifiy controller method parameter

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/removeproductcategory", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json" )
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> removeProductCategory(@RequestBody RequestData pcId,
                                                  HttpServletRequest request)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. In fact, the foreground needs to make a change. The data sent should be in JSON format.So the foreground only needs to add the following sentence -- "JSON.stringify(pcId)"